# Git and Team Explorer with Multiple Levels of Branch Depth and Merging through Pull Requests

Tags: git, tfs, merge, branch, pull-request

We're using TFS and recently (within the last month) switched to Git VC. We have policies in place so manually merging into the master branch isn't allowed. Instead, we have pull requests with policies in place that only allow a merge to master if the pull request is approved.

I've come across the following scenario:

1. Created local branch `BranchA` from `master`
2. Completed development on `BranchA`, opened a pull request relative to `master`
3. Created local branch `BranchB` from `BranchA`, as `BranchB` relies on the code in `BranchA`
4. Completed development on `BranchB`, opened a pull request relative to `BranchA`

I understand Git doesn't have the concept of pull requests, and strictly speaking, merging the branches together poses no real concern. That is:

`BranchB` merged to `BranchA` merged to `master` is just as fine as doing
`BranchB` merged to `master`, then `BranchA` merged to `master`

I'm struggling to discern the cleanest way to perform the merging when pull requests are involved. What I've done is:

1. Complete pull request for `BranchB` which merges `BranchB` into `BranchA`
2. Complete pull request for `BranchA` which merges `BranchA` into `master`

Unfortunately, this approach caused `BranchA`'s pull request to be updated with the latest changes from `BranchB`, which bloats the pull request and takes away its original intent (as now there are many more files to review).

If I switch the order so `BranchA` pull request is completed, I'd have to ensure the remote branch isn't deleted, because `BranchB` relies on its existence (this is an assumption, perhaps TFS decouples the pull request from the physical branch?).

If I make `BranchB`'s pull request relative to `master`, then the pull request will include both `BranchA` and `BranchB` changes, since `master` doesn't know of `BranchA` yet.

I'm looking for any advice on how to handle this scenario without bloating the pull requests.

Comment: You can delete the branch in your second scenario just fine, the branch isn't much more than a "label" on a specific commit. As long as there are other commits still referencing these commits, they will not be gone. How could you speed up the merge process so BranchB could start of master?

Comment: Ah, that's a very good point and important that I remember, branches are just labels, commits are the real deal. So in that case order doesn't matter, `BranchA` could merge first. As for speeding up merging, that's a matter of having other members of the team finish reviewing and approving the code (our merge policy requires 2 approvers before merge occurs). Ideally these pull requests would be short-lived, but that's not always the case. Also, I'd typically be ready to start dev on `BranchB` almost immediately after opening a pull request for `BranchA`

Answer (score 0):

A `pull request` is a `fetch` followed by a `merge`. And just like you said in the comment branches are just labels, commits are the real deal.

A workaround for your case could be merge a pull request in two branches.For example directly create a pull request from `BranchB` relative to `master`. After the pull request be accepted. To now merge it in `BranchA` you could simply do this in your local repo: `git checkout` the  BranchA, `git merge` with `BranchB` (or commit you're trying to `merge` with), and then `git push` your local `BranchA` branch to the remote repo's `BranchA` branch.

```
git checkout Branch A
git merge Branch B
git push origin Branch B
```